# Como hacer que la barra de navegación no se coma la parte superior de la pantalla

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Buenas!

He creado una barra de navegación para mi página vertical, el problema es que como se ve en la siguiente foto, al enlazarme a las secciones, la barra se come parte de dicha sección. Le he puesto fondo transparente para que se se vea mejor lo que pasa.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi intención es que quede de la siguiente manera: (que no se vería tan mal, porque en realidad tiene un fondo negro)
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Es decir, que la sección se vea entera, por decirlo de alguna manera, que se ponga al final de la sección anterior.

Mi código es el siguiente:

```css
HEADER {
  height: 80px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: transparent;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 10;
  transition: background-color 0.3s;
}

#Barra-Navegacion {
  display: table;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 15px;
  height: 40px;
  transition: margin-left 0.3s;
}

#Barra-Navegacion ul {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  list-style: none;
}

img#Logo {
  height: 60px;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 30px;
  float: left;
  transition: width 0.3s, height 0.3s, margin-top 0.3s, margin-right 0.3s;
}

#Barra-Navegacion ul li {
  float: left;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
}

#Barra-Navegacion ul li a {
  color: #FFF;
  opacity: 0.8;
}

#Barra-Navegacion ul li a:visited {
  color: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<HEADER>

  <nav id="Barra-Navegacion">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#Portada">Portada</a></li>
      <li><a href="#Conoceme">Mis destrezas</a></li>
      <li><a href="#Mis-Proyectos">Mis proyectos</a></li>
    </ul>

    <img id="Logo" src="Img/logo200px.png" alt="Logo NEA">

    <ul>
      <li><a href="#Contacto">¿Trabajamos juntos?</a></li>
      <li><a href="#Mis-Datos">¿Nos vemos?</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>

</HEADER>
```

Y lo que hago para que se redireccione es poner en `html` : `<a name="Contactos"></a>` en el inicio de su contenedor.

¿Hay alguna manera para que eso no se superponga encima, si no que lo trate como bloque?

Comment: al header añadele top:0; y left:0;

Comment: Y z-index:9999;

Comment: Con top:0 y left:0 no hago nada, porque el ya se va a esa posición. El problema es que así se come por ejemplo el título del sitio a donde te lleva, como se ve en la primera imagen.

Comment: Reedite mi respuesta, haz esos cambios

Comment: Se me ocurre una pequeña chapuza: cuando se haga click en un "anchor", se va a hacer un scroll. Captura el evento y réstale al scrollY la altura de tu barra

Answer (score 0):

```
Position: absolute;
z-index: 9999;
```

eso deberia obligar a la barra a ponerse encima de cualquier objeto que tengas en el html, claro adaptando el TOP y LEFT para que quede siempre al extremo izquierdo.